# Is it possible to have progress reporting for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(File)?

Tags: java, xml, dom

If execution of [`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) takes a long time, may I obtain somehow the progress information from somewhere? May be add some hooks or progress listeners?

Comment: based on the documentation, the answer is no.

Comment: Did you think about using SAX API? It is event based and you can add listeners to update the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I've got: DocumentBuilder.parse() does have  variants which will read from a provided stream or reader. So write an instrumented version of FileInputStream/FileReader that reports how far it has read through the file (vs. the file's total length), and pass that to the parser.